# Jquery triggering click event on each element of array

Tags: jquery, triggers, click

I want to trigger click from jquery code on each element of dynamically created array containing DOM elements (buttons, checkboxes etc).
This code is not working

```
 checkAllChilds: function(elements) {
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.Length; i++) {
            $(elements[i]).click();
        }
```

Comment: It's `length`, not `Length`. Besides, `$(elements).click()` will do as well.

Comment: What a stupid mistake :) Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Here it is. As simple as that:

```js
elements = $("button, div, span");


$(elements).click(function(){
  //console.log($(this));
  console.log( $(this).text() );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button>button</button><br>
<div>div</div>
<span>span</span>
```